# How do I restart/reload Apache when it can't determine the domain name?

Tags: apache2, restart

After installing [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) I tried to restart or reload Apache and I received the following message:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server config apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain
name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

Comment: And your question is ... ? If you think the notice should not be shown here are several answers: http://www.google.nl/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=Could+not+reliably+determine+the+server's+fully+qualified+domain+name%2C+using+127.0.0.1+for+ServerName . And it is NOT an error but a notice it is using localhost as FQDN.

Comment: CLOSING OF THIS QUESTION. This problem of solved inserting the following line in the file apache2.conf:"ServerName localhost". It has taken some time because of search in the web. What would not happen if anybody could answer rapidly. Anyway thanks attention.

Comment: @franktavares can you post this as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 18):

Good news! Apache is restarting successfully. Apache just isn't sure where you want serve from, so it's choosing your [localhost](http://127.0.0.1) by default. To prevent this message from appearing, clarify that you want to serve from [localhost](http://127.0.0.1) by adding the following line into your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file:

```
ServerName localhost
```