# Problem with restarting Apache 2

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to restart Apache 2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But get the below error:

```
* Restarting web server apache2 

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1.

Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I've tried to change

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

A blank file appears, and I'd added this:

```
ServerName localhost
```

But that error doesn't disappear!

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: well have you checked the link I posted? The error is clearly the same. try "my" Answer below.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I found this: [How do I restart/reload Apache when it can't determine the domain name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80714/how-do-i-restart-reload-apache-when-it-cant-determine-the-domain-name)

> Good news! Apache is restarting successfully. Apache just isn't sure
>   where you want serve from, so it's choosing your localhost (127.0.0.1)
>   by default. To prevent this message from appearing, clarify that you
>   want to serve from localhost (127.0.0.1) by adding the following line
>   into your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file:
>
> ```
> ServerName localhost
> ```

Comment: Optionally you can add this under the "Global Configuration" section. Order doesn't matter, but if you're trying to find it later this helps for organization.

Comment: In newer versions of Ubuntu, it may make more sense to put it in /etc/apache2/conf-available/ServerName.conf and then run 'sudo a2enconf ServerName'. This way you don't change the app controlled config and you will override it if it does get changed in a future version for some reason.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. I up voted this answer.

Answer (score 35):

Specifying `ServerName localhost` in your configuration files outside of the virtual host sections is the way to do this.

Other answers suggest that you should modify `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.  This file gets overwritten when apache gets upgraded from apt.  For Apache configuration that you don't want to get overwritten, you should create a new file.  Here is the "Debian way" to make this configuration change:

```
# create the configuration file in the "available" section
echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf
# enable it by creating a symlink to it from the "enabled" section
sudo a2enconf servername
# restart the server
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: more clean solution maybe

Answer (score 5):

Your localhost IP Address should be 127.0.0.1, instead of 127.0.1.1. Please setup your `/etc/hosts` file properly. Then edit the `httpd.conf` file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

When a blank file appears, please add this line, then save:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Solution:

#### Before:

```
[root@centos ~]# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for centos.wks.local
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

Added `192.168.226.131                centos.wks.local` in `/etc/hosts` file

Note: 192.168.226.131 is my Apache server IP address.

#### After:

```
[root@centos ~]# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

Comment: No `/etc/init.d/httpd` for Apache on Ubuntu. It's `/etc/init.d/apache2`. Just pointing out.

Comment: Yes, it's from CentOS but solution will work, because it's required FQDN

Comment: Editing `/etc/hosts` is quite bad practice to say the least.